# Updating global variables in class functions

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm having trouble with the "mixed" operation in my program. When mixed is selected, I want it to ask a mix of addition, subtraction, division, and multiplication questions. However, not only does it always ask division questions (because of the else statement), but it also displays "&" as the option. I've tried to set the option to operation, but I get a local variable error.

I've tried to revise my code as much as possible and isolate the crucial code. Because of this, you'll probably need to start the program more than once.

```
# Imported modules
import random
import tkinter as ttk1
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font

root = Tk()
root.title("Mathz for FUN!")

# Frame Changer
def change_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)

f1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
f2.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')
f3.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='NSEW')

# Option & Mode Selector
option = ""
def select_question(value):
    global option
    option = value
    app.generate_question()

mode = ""
def select_mode(value):
    global mode
    mode = value
    app.generate_question()


# Frame 1
third_frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(f1, text="Difficulty")
third_frame1.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

mode_label = ttk.Label(third_frame1, text="Choose addition or subtraction, or just a mix of all. It's up to you!")
mode_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=12, padx=20, pady=10)

radio1 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="plus", value="Addition", command=lambda:select_question("+"))
radio1.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=18)

radio2 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="minus", value="Subtraction", command=lambda:select_question("-"))
radio2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=18)

radio3 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="times", value="Multiplication", command=lambda:select_question("*"))
radio3.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=18)

radio4 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="divide", value="Division", command=lambda:select_question("/"))
radio4.grid(row=2, column=3, padx=18)

radio5 = ttk.Radiobutton(third_frame1, text="mixed", value="Mixed", command=lambda:select_question("&"))
radio5.grid(row=2, column=4)

# Fourth Frame
fourth_frame1 = ttk.LabelFrame(f1, text="Challenge")
fourth_frame1.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="NSEW")

challenge_label = ttk.Label(fourth_frame1, text="Make and beat your high score or see how many questions you can get correct with three lives!")
challenge_label.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=5, padx=20, pady=10)

radio_var = StringVar()
radio6 = ttk.Radiobutton(fourth_frame1, text="Easy", value="Easy", variable=radio_var, command=lambda:select_mode("1"))
radio6.grid(row=2, column=1)

radio7 = ttk.Radiobutton(fourth_frame1, text="Medium", value="Medium", variable=radio_var, command=lambda:select_mode("2"))
radio7.grid(row=2, column=2)

radio7 = ttk.Radiobutton(fourth_frame1, text="Hard", value="Hard", variable=radio_var, command=lambda:select_mode("3"))
radio7.grid(row=2, column=3)

def start_game():
    if option and mode:
            change_frame(f2)
            
start = ttk.Button(fourth_frame1, text="Start", command=start_game)
start.grid(row=3, column=2, pady=3)


# Frame 2
# Top Frame
top_frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(f2, text="Question", height=100, width=200)
top_frame2.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, rowspan=2, padx=20, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")


# Fourth Frame
fourth_frame2 = ttk.LabelFrame(f2)
fourth_frame2.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=12, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="NSEW")

class Question:
    def __init__(self, root1):
        self.root1 = root1
        self.set_values()
        self.question_entry()

    def set_values(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.lives = 3
        self.current_question = 0
        
    def question_entry(self):
        self.question = ttk1.Label(top_frame2, text="")
        self.question.grid(pady=20)   
        
    def generate_question(self):
        num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
        num2 = random.randint(1, 10)          

        if option == "&":
            operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
            operation = random.choice(operators)
            operation = option
        if option == "+":
            self.correct_answer = num1 + num2
        elif option == "-":
            self.correct_answer = num1 - num2
        elif option == "*":
            self.correct_answer = num1 * num2
        else:
            num1, num2 = num1 * num2, num1
            self.correct_answer = num1 // num2         
        
        self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} {option} {num2}?")


app = Question(root)

change_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Surely this line: `operation = option` is a mistake and should be deleted. You overwrite the randomly chosen choice from `operators`.

Comment: Or perhaps you meant `option = operation` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when the "mixed" option is selected, the code assigns the value of option to the operation variable, but it doesn't use it to generate the question. Instead, it always generates a division question because of the else statement.
To fix this, you can remove the else statement and modify the if condition for the "mixed" option, updated the `generate_question` method:

```
def generate_question(self):
   num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
   num2 = random.randint(1, 10)

   if option == "&":
       operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
       operation = random.choice(operators)
       if operation == '+':
          self.correct_answer = num1 + num2
       elif operation == '-':
          self.correct_answer = num1 - num2
       elif operation == '*':
           self.correct_answer = num1 * num2
       else:
           num1, num2 = num1 * num2, num1
           self.correct_answer = num1 // num2
       self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} {operation} {num2}?")
    elif option == "+":
        self.correct_answer = num1 + num2
        self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} + {num2}?")
    elif option == "-":
        self.correct_answer = num1 - num2
        self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} - {num2}?")
    elif option == "*":
        self.correct_answer = num1 * num2
        self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} * {num2}?")
    else:
        num1, num2 = num1 * num2, num1
        self.correct_answer = num1 // num2
        self.question.config(text=f"What is {num1} / {num2}?")
```

when the "mixed" option is selected, it randomly selects an operator from the list of operators and  the program will ask a mix of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division questions.